# Azure Bot Service - "Couldn't send retry" on emulator

Tags: botframework

I have created two bots via the Azure portal today (NodeJS blank & language understanding) and both bots don't work.
If I launch the emulator in the portal and send a message it states "Couldn't send retry" and the console shows the following:

[image: Azure Bot Service console & error in emulator]

On the Channels tab under Web Chat it shows the following errors:

[image: Channel Web Chat error message]

My previously created bots work however.

Has anyone an idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Please report this issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new

Comment: Note: Bot Service bots are based on Azure Functions - this means the first response from your bot can sometimes be delayed since the Functions app is "asleep" until messages are actually sent to it.

Comment: It looks like the latest release of the botbuilder package introduces this issue, please try to force the version to the previous one (3.12.0) in the package.json.
If the UI does not update the packages, you'll need to go to kudu https://<your-bot-name->.scm.azurewebsites.net, then select CMD from the Debug Console menu, navigate to site\wwwroot\messages, and type npm update

Comment: Hi Stephan, which region(s) are your bots deployed to, and can you confirm you're still running into the same issues?

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for the info, that did the trick for me!

Comment: I have also done a blog post on this issue and the solution: https://www.cloudguy.pro/azure-bot-service-couldnt-send-error-emulator/

Comment: This issue has been patched and fixed in `botbuilder@3.13.1`